# How to get an external data source query to select column data in the where clause

Tags: mysql, sql-server, excel

I'm not sure if this is possible but I'm trying to create an SQL query inside in an excel file that uses a data range inside the sheet in there where clause.

The short version of the query is this

```
select * from customerOfferScheduledTask as COST 

where COST.id in (?)
```

I tries setting the parameter to the data range I wanted in this example = Table1[Task Final] (see below) but it said it had to be one cell, I also tried a formula to create the date list in one cell and reference that but the query would only bring back data for the 1st value.

Any help would be grateful

```
Task 1  Task Final
1702219 1702219,
1700757 1700757,
1702219 1702219,
1801058 1801058,
1657646 1657646,
1525730 1525730
```